# Read line by line from a file and save in a list C

Tags: c, list, file

My problem is to read from a file with 100 lines, each line with 4 fields(separated by 4 spaces), which looks like this:

`0007   0007    NOVO BANCO, SA    Bancos`

`0008   0008    BANCO BAI EUROPA, SA    Bancos`

`0010   0010    BANCO BPI, SA   Bancos`

etc...

After doing this i have to save it in a linked list.

Atm i have this:

```
struct list{
    int code1;
    int code2;
    char name[100];
    char type[100];
    struct list *next, *current;    
};

int main()
{

    FILE *fp1;
    struct list iban;

    fp1 = fopen("ibanlist.txt", "r");
    if(fopen == NULL)
    {
         printf("Error!");
    }

    fscanf(fp1, /*what should i do here?*/, iban.code1, iban.code2, iban.name, iban.type);
    //should i use fgets and sscanf instead?

    fclose(fp1);
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is how to read from the file with the spaces. For example in the third field it has a space after the ','. Also its the first time im using lists, can anyone give me a head start how to do it?

Comment: how about reading bytes (unformatted input) to a buffer (say until you read at least a line), split the buffer by finding the four-space-tokens and then `scanf` from the buffer-chunks?

Comment: The [`scanf` family of functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) is probably not the correct choice here, as it would consider `"NOVO BANCO, SA"` to be three strings not one.

Comment: Also fscanf() would use **&(iban.code1)** and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses `strstr` to tokenise the input string. The first delimiter in the data is only 3 spaces, the rest are 4, so in each case I look for 3 and then advance past all consecutive spaces.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct list{
    int code1;
    int code2;
    char name[100];
    char type[100];
};

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char str [1000];
    char *aptr, *bptr, *cptr;
    struct list rec;

    if ((fp = fopen("file.txt", "rt")) == NULL)
        return 1;

    while(fgets(str, sizeof str, fp) != NULL) {
        // break the input line
        aptr = strstr(str, "   ");              // isolate first field
        if(aptr == NULL)
            return 1;
        *aptr++ = '\0';
        while (*aptr == ' ')
            aptr++;

        bptr = strstr(aptr, "   ");             // isolate second field
        if(bptr == NULL)
            return 1;
        *bptr++ = '\0';
        while (*bptr == ' ')
            bptr++;

        cptr = strstr(bptr, "   ");             // isolate third field
        if(cptr == NULL)
            return 1;
        *cptr++ = '\0';
        while (*cptr == ' ')
            cptr++;

        cptr [ strcspn(cptr, "\r\n") ] = 0;    // remove trailing newline etc

        // extract the data
        if(sscanf(str, "%d", &rec.code1) != 1)
            return 1;
        if(sscanf(aptr, "%d", &rec.code2) != 1)
            return 1;
        strcpy(rec.name, bptr);
        strcpy(rec.type, cptr);

        // print the result
        printf("%d/%d/%s/%s\n", rec.code1, rec.code2, rec.name, rec.type);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
7/7/NOVO BANCO, SA/Bancos
8/8/BANCO BAI EUROPA, SA/Bancos
10/10/BANCO BPI, SA/Bancos
```

Comment: A similar approach to the answer from @MOehm - but written idependently not cribbed!

Comment: "but written idependently not cribbed" - I know `:)`. Plus it's adopted to the OP's actual problem. Nice.

Comment: @MOehm it was only when I returned to the page to collect the input data that I saw you had beat me to it. I like your idea of making a function to do the splitting.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to tokenise the string at, say, three or more consecutive spaces. You would then convert the ids with `strtol` or similar functions.

One way to do so is to search for three spaces with `strstr` and then skip spaces after that.

The following short program implements a variant of `strtok` hat splits a string at three or more spaces. Like `strtok`, it modifies your string, so make sure that you pass a modifiable char array.

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    char *token(char *str)
    {
        static char *p;
        char *res;

        if (str) p = str;
        if (p == NULL) return p;

        while (*p == ' ') p++;
        if (*p == '\0') return NULL;
        res = p;

        p = strstr(p, "   ");

        if (p && *p) {
            *p = '\0';
            p++;
        }

        return res;
    }

    int main()
    {
        char str[] = "0008   0008    BANCO BAI EUROPA, SA    Bancos";
        char *t;

        t = token(str);
        while (t) {
            puts(t);
            t = token(NULL);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```